# How to Add Full Width Background Image in Joomla 3x

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to add a full width background image for a div in an article in Joomla 3x, but I have no idea how. The article or modules can add the suffix class but only applied for the article's  or module's div, still not full width.

code example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="article-wrapper">article here</div>
</div>
```

The suffix class I can add is to *article-wrapper* only, but I need to add into *container*.

Anyone help?

Comment: Try using an inline style `style="background: url('image.jpg') center top no-repeat; background-size: cover;"` or post some code so we have something to work with.

Comment: @MichaelCoker added a simple code example! :D

Comment: A link to a live website would help.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is [add a custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120) specifying a suitable selector and background image like this or similar:

```
#content { 
  background: url(background-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The selector will depend on the template so you'll need to do some digging with FireBug or Developer Tools or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. But this `.container` div should be full width too.

```
.container { 
    background: url(background-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If you have more then one `.container` divs on that page then you will have to use the child selector. ie

```
#maincontainer .container:firstchild {
    //code here//
}
```